# How to re-order pandas dataframe columns based on values in particular row?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying re-order columns based on rank assigned to each column. The rank is in a row for each column. The DataFrame is structured as below.

| index | Attributes | 3_LR | 2_RFC | 4_LR | 1_RFC | 2_LR | 1_LR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | experiment_id | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | run_id | 3 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | model_id | LR | RFC | LR | RFC | LR | LR |
| 3 | Model_rank | 3 | 6 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | f1 | 94.2 | 87.4 | 94.2 | 87.4 | 94.2 | 94.2 |

And I am expecting the output as below (Sorting columns based on row 'Model_rank'))

| index | Attributes | 1_LR | 2_LR | 3_LR | 4_LR | 1_RFC | 2_RFC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | experiment_id | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | run_id | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | model_id | LR | LR | LR | LR | RFC | RFC |
| 3 | Model_rank | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 4 | f1 | 94.2 | 94.2 | 94.2 | 94.2 | 87.4 | 87.4 |

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: I have edited the question and added expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets your dataframe is:

```
# List of Tuples
matrix = [(222, 16, 23),
          (333, 31, 11),
          (444, 34, 11),
          ]
# Create a DataFrame object of 3X3 Matrix
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(matrix, index=list('abc'))
dfObj
```

output:

```
     0   1   2
a  222  16  23
b  333  31  11
c  444  34  11
```

Now for example sort based on row indexed by "b":

```
dfObj = dfObj.sort_values(by ='b', axis=1)
dfObj
```

output would be:

```
    2   1   0
a   23  16  222
b   11  31  333
c   11  34  444
```